# Количество совпадений для каждого элемента List<string>

Tags: c#, list

На входе `List<string>`, который содержит каждый раз разное количество элементов. Он передается в

```
    private static bool HandleElement (XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer, List<string> tag_list )
    {
        if (tag_list.Contains(reader.Name))
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("element", "val");
            writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");
            reader.Skip();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Вместо `val` мне необходимо число, сколько раз на данный момент встречался данный элемент в xml файле.
Например пусть `List<string>` содержит `"a" "b"` и при чтении xml мы встретили `"a"` второй раз, тогда `val` будет равен 2. Т.е. грубо говоря вести счетчик для каждой элемента `List`.
Пробовал через `Tuple <string, int>`, но в нем нельзя менять значения.

Comment: Уберите `writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");`. При создании XmlWriter'а используйте `XmlWriterSettings` с `Indent = true`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Стоит так, но пишет все равно в одну строку

Comment: Значит, что-то делаете неправильно. Должно писать с отступами, форматированно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Делаю вот так   `var ws = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true};` использую так `using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("new_xml_file.xml", ws)) { ... }` Сам не пойму почему так

Comment: Гм, всё верно. Должно работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> TagCounter = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private static bool HandleElement(XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer, List<string> tag_list)
{
    var tagName = reader.Name;

    if (tag_list.Contains(tagName))
    {
        if (TagCounter.ContainsKey(tagName))
            TagCounter[tagName]++;
        else
            TagCounter.Add(tagName, 1);

        writer.WriteElementString("element", tagName + ":" +TagCounter[tagName]);
        writer.WriteWhitespace("\n");
        reader.Skip();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: А для чего вы используете readonly ?

Comment: Ну, он необязателен. Нужен для защиты переменной от перезаписи.